# find the highest scoring word in a string, but i keep getting error that subscript out of range

Tags: c++, string, loops

> Given a string of words, you need to find the highest scoring word.
>
> Each letter of a word scores points according to its position in the alphabet: a = 1, b = 2, c = 3 etc.
>
> You need to return the highest scoring word as a string.
>
> If two words score the same, return the word that appears earliest in the original string.
>
> All letters will be lowercase and all inputs will be valid.

I know there are many ways to solve it, but I am not familiar with some advanced techniques. So I just use `while` loops and `std::string` to solve it. but I keep getting a "subscript out of range" error.

I appreciate if you can have a look at my code and see what the problem is:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string highestScoringWord(const string& str)
{
    int i = 0;
    int max = 0;
    int total = 0;
    int highest = 0;

    while (i < str.length())
    {
        if (str[i] == ' ')
        {
            if (total > max)
            {
                highest = i-1;
                max = total;
                i = i + 1;
                total = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                total = 0;
                i = i + 1;
            }
        }

        total += int(str[i]);
        if (i == str.length() - 1 && total > max)
        {
            highest = i;
        }
        i++;
    }

    string h = "";
    i = highest;
    while (str[i] != ' '&& i >=0)
    {
        h += str[i];
        i--;
    }

    int l = h.length();
    for (int c = 0; c < (l/2); c++)
    {
        char temp = h[i];
        h[i] = h[(l - 1 - i)];
        h[(l - 1 - i)] = temp;

    }
    return h;
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details as to the error, and how one might recreate the problem.

Comment: Did you run your code through a debugger? Step through your program, and find out where you are indexing the string with an invalid subscript.

Comment: One way to figure out where your out of range subscript is to change all of your `std::string::operator[]` to `std::string::at` calls (`str[i]` would become `str.at(i)` for example). Or you can step through with your debugger.

Comment: How do you know that `str[i]` is still valid after `i = i + 1;`?

Comment: Apparently you have a very good debugger which is already pointing you to the error (out of range access). Use it wisely, it's telling exactly where the error in your code is.

Comment: After you find out where your error is (which is a good exercise in debugging) you should change your approach to compartmentalize your approach: first, separate all your words into a vector of strings. Next, find the score of each of those strings. You turn fiddly-bit index-scrolling into simple vector iteration.

Comment: Your variable `i` may be equal to `str.length()` at this line: `total += int(str[i]);` but you don't check.

Comment: I thought str[i] is still valid because if (str[I] == "  ") then i = i+1; and white space only appears between words so i += 1 will point to the first character of next word @Yksisarvinen

Comment: error shows at while(str[I] != '  ' && i >= 0) it shows that i(highest) = -1 @ScottHunter